# display array list using lightning-datatable in html LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components

I tried to display my array using lightning-datatable with the below code. However, I can see the table and overview of datatable but no data is displayed in the table. Please help me to identify my where the mistake was.

**JS**:

```js
import { LightningElement,track,api } from 'lwc';
const columns = [
  {label:'Name',fieldname:'name'},
  {label:'Email',fieldname:'email'},
  {label:'Phone',fieldname:'phone'}
];
export default class Form extends LightningElement {
  
    @track name;
    @track displayAll = false;
    @track stu = {};
    @track columns = columns;  
    @track nameList = [
        {
            Id : 1,
            name : 'Sumo',
            email : 'a@a.com',
            phone : 9778787
        },
        {
            Id : 2,
            name : 'Sumi',
            email : 'b@a.com',
            phone : 9778788
        },
        {
            Id : 3,
            name : 'Asif',
            email : 'c@a.com',
            phone : 9778787
        }
    ];

    displayNames(event)
    {
        this.displayAll = this.displayAll? false :true;
        showToast(this,'info','List of Records');
    }
}
```

**HTML**:

```html
<template>
    <lightning-card title="Search,Delete, and Display">
        <div class="slds-medium">                 
        <lightning-input label="Name" data-inputname="name" type="text" value={stu.name} onchange={getName}></lightning-input><br/>
        <lightning-input label="Email" data-inputname="email" type="text" value={stu.email} onchange={getName}></lightning-input><br/>
        <lightning-input label="Phone" data-inputname="phone" type="number" value={stu.phone} onchange={getName}></lightning-input>
    </div>
        <div>
            <lightning-button-group>
                <lightning-button label="Display" onclick={displayNames}></lightning-button>
            </lightning-button-group>
        </div>
        <template if:true={displayAll}>
               <lightning-datatable columns={columns} data={nameList} key-field="Id"></lightning-datatable>
        </template>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike APEX, JavaScript is [case sentive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Case_sensitivity). It means that in your code you may have `var sOMetHINg;` and `var something;` and they will be different variable.

In order to use a [datatable](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-datatable/documentation), the columns object must have some required properties.
One of them is `fieldName`, but in the controller you wrote `fieldname`, so the datatable doesn't know which attribute of the provided data it has to show.

To fix this issue just change

```
const columns = [
  {label:'Name',fieldname:'name'},
  {label:'Email',fieldname:'email'},
  {label:'Phone',fieldname:'phone'}
];
```

to

```
const columns = [
  { label:'Name', fieldName:'name' },
  { label:'Email', fieldName:'email', type: 'email' },
  { label:'Phone', fieldName:'phone', type: 'phone' }
];
```

By the way, in the `displayNames` method you call `showToast`, but it isn't defined in your class (at least in the snippet you posted), so that line will rise an exception.
Moreover `this.displayAll = this.displayAll? false :true;` can be rewritten as `this.displayAll = !this.displayAll;`

Keep in mind that field used in the HTML template [are already reactive](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/reactivity_fields), so you don't need `@track` decorator in such cases, but only to

> observe changes to the properties of an object or to the elements of an array

Comment: Thanks! It works!. actually, showToast is another js file imported in the main js and I haven't included the entire code in the snippet, added only the errored code. Thanks!